# ¿En qué países se dice "comer" en el mediodía y en cuáles en la noche?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, comida

El DRAE indica que:

> **[comer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9vPNMxG%7C9vRLW2D)**
>
> 8. intr. Tomar la **comida** (‖ alimento que se toma al mediodía). Hoy no como en casa.
> 9. intr. Tomar la **cena** (‖ última comida del día).

Y luego tenemos que:

> **[comida](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9w3sObI)**
>
> <sub>De comer.</sub>
>
> 2. f. Alimento que se toma al mediodía o primeras horas de la tarde.
> 3. f. cena<sup>1</sup>.
>
> **[cena](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8Bs26eN)**
>
> <sub>Del lat. cena.</sub>
>
> 1. f. Última comida del día, que se toma al atardecer o por la noche.

En mi experiencia, en España decimos "comer" a tomar el alimento que se toma al mediodía, pero en Colombia se refieren a la última del día.

¿En qué países se usa cada una de las formas?

Comment: Creo que a falta de una fuente, sólo podemos responder país por país. **Chile**: mediodía--> _almuerzo_, **noche**--> _comida_ (_cena_ es usado, pero mayormente como forma de sobrecorrección)

Comment: @Rafael creé una respuesta wiki donde ir añadiendo esta información. Puedes editarla tanto como quieras : ) Ya puse Chile, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Comer* al mediodía:

- España
- México

*Comer* por la noche:

- Chile
- Colombia
- Costa Rica
- Cuba
- Perú
- Puerto Rico
- Venezuela