# ¿Cómo se dice "to have a meal"?

Tags: traducción, modismos, comida

¿Cómo se puede decir "to have a meal" en español (eg 'I have 3 meals every day')?

"Comer/tener/hacer una comida"?

No puedo encontrarlo en Word Reference y no estoy seguro  si la traducción de Google ("tener una comida") es correcta.

Comment: Note that _comida_ is also the name for the meal at night and that _comer_ is sometimes just referred to either _lunchtime meal_ or _meal at night_. See [¿En qué países se dice “comer” en el mediodía y en cuáles en la noche?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16796/1674)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For

> **I have three meals every day**

You can say

> **Hago tres comidas diarias**

See this [article from Spain](https://cronicaglobal.elespanol.com/cronica-directo/error-tres-comidas-dia_76653_102.html) in which the dietary benefit of making three meals a day is objected

```
 Las sociedad avanzadas se han acostumbrado a hacer tres comidas al día.
```

Note that this form is often used with nutritional or dietary purposes, a more straightforward way —as pointed already— would be to simply say:

> **Como tres veces al dia** / **Como tres comidas diariamente**

For what you also ask **tener una comida** is not correct in that intend, but it is used to mean that you are either invited or hosting a meal with friends or other people.

> Esta noche **tengo una comida** con amigos

Comment: Una pequeña puntualización, si es por la noche, es raro decir una comida. Es más natural decir "una cena". En ese contexto se usa "comida" si es al mediodía.

Comment: `Hacer comida` means to make food, to cook, and not really to have a meal, to have some food. For example `tengo que hacer la comida para mañana` would mean "I have to cook for tomorrow" or "I have to make food for tomorrow".

Comment: @VladimirNul I don't agree with you. "Hago tres comidas al día" does not imply that you elaborate the food. It depends on the context. For example in "Hago dieta", you are not making no-food. In relation with "dieta", you can perfectly say "Estoy siguiendo una dieta especial, ahora hago cinco comidas al día" meaning that you have five meals per day. You may or may not cook them.

Comment: @RubioRic seguramente hay variaciones regionales, soy de Argentina, donde llamar cena a una comida con amigos tiene una implicancia demasiado formal

Comment: @user2325442 Puede ser. Quizás lo de "tengo una cena" también implique cierta formalidad en mi zona de España, pero ya es el contexto y el resto de palabras el que termina de definir esa formalidad. "Tengo una cena" [formal]; "Tengo una cena con amigos" [neutro]; "He quedado para cenar" [informal]. Lo de tengo una comida por la noche me sigue sonando raro, pero es lo que comentas, diferencias regionales.

Comment: Para hacer claro cuando me refiero al acto de cocinar, prefiero decir *Hago de comer tres veces al día* o *Cocino tres veces al día* porque de ésta forma queda claro que no es comer tres veces sino cocinar tres veces.

Comment: @RubioRic en el comentario de la pregunta hay un enlace de en que lugares se come "a mediodía" y en donde se come "de noche", quizá por eso te puede sonar raro a ti pero no por eso es raro para millones de hispanohablantes

Comment: @VeAqui Ya había quedado aclarado en los comentarios de arriba. Creo que no era necesario abundar en el tema ni mencionar los millones que no hablan exactamente como yo. Ni como tú.

Answer (score 5):

[The answer by @user2325442](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31682/1674) is certainly a precise translation of "I have three meals a day" -- but I would like to add that 99.9% of the time, the way this sentence would be expressed in Spanish is

> Como tres veces al día.

Backtranslating, we get *I eat three times per day.*

This is the *functional* translation of "I have three meals a day."

Answer (score -1):

> Como se puede decir "to have a meal" en español (eg I have 3 meals every day)? "comer/tener/hacer una comida" ? I cannot find it in Word Reference and I am not sure if the Google Translation ("tener una comida") is correct.

**"Tener una comida" would very likely mean (at least in european variant) an appointment to have lunch with other people, possibly business related. Don't use it like that.**

As [this](//spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31683/23419) points out, "como tres veces al día" is perfectly acceptable.

As [this](//spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31682/23419) points out, "hago tres comidas diarias" is even better (at least for european variant).

Another alternative, acceptable in european variant, would be "me/te/se/nos/os hago/haces/hace/hacemos/hacéis/hacen de comer tres veces al día". You would hear this very likely in Andalusia, southernmost Spain, as a fully interchangeable variant of "hago tres comidas diarias", when the food is being cooked at home by someone.

Comment: Please, colleagues and friends, let's provide feedback when downvoting, especially when it's a new participant.

Comment: I appreciate your concern, but native newcomers don't... really need this kind of support! ;) At least not me.

Comment: Well, it's considered courteous to explain downvotes in general.  Not just newcomers.

Comment: I also find very exhausting trying to fight with [the software's rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com) rather than simply accepting or rejecting them. :/